# Two questions about non-abelian finite simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

In OEIS, I found the positive integers $\ n\ $ , for which there exists a non-abelian simple group with order $\ n\ $ upto $\ 10^{10}\ $. It can be found by entering the numbers $\ 60,168,360\ $

- Only two of the numbers , [29120, 32537600] , are not divisible by $\ 12\ $.

  Question 1 : Is every other number in this sequence divisble by $\ 12\ $ ?
- In the list of simple groups in Wikipedia I noticed that the only positive integer $\ n\le 10^5\ $ , such there are at least two non-isomorphic non-abelian simple groups with order $\ n\ $ , is $\ n=20160\ $.

  Question 2 : Is this the only such integer, and if not ,what is the second-smallest. Given the Referrence to Hall listing $\ 56\ $ groups and considering the OEIS-sequence , it should be larger than $\ 10^6\ $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Suzuki groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzuki_groups) are simple groups whose orders are not divisible
by $3$ and *a fortiori* are not divisible by $12$.

Comment: (+1) Do you also have an idea about question 2 ?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107620/non-isomorphic-finite-simple-groups @Peter

Comment: The answer to 2 is 4585351680.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you

Comment: @AnginaSeng Is the order always divisible by $4$ ?

Comment: @Peter Yes. It is even by Feit-Thompson, and it is an easy argument that a group of twice odd order has a characteristic subgroup of index 2. It is always divisible by 12, except for the Suzuki groups.